# Critique: Morse Code for logo?

Tags: logo, critique

So I'm slowly going about teaching myself about design and I'd love to hear what you think about this.

I chose Morse Code because at first I couldn't come up with anything comprised of my initials R and U and secondly, because I was fascinated by it not a long time ago.

Is there any way I can make this logo look better using Morse Code?
More importantly, by using Morse Code does this look like logo material?

[image]

Comment: This is funky. If you're looking for further development or just for having some fun with it; I see a face, a little disgruntled but a face. You could play a lot with this while still keeping it simple. :)

Comment: @jenna Hey there's a face in everything... Human nature. But maybe it can be built on...

Comment: That's true @joojaa I think it's particularly prominent here though and with a rather distinctive expression, perhaps even style. I agree though, there is of course a face in everything!

Comment: @Jenna I am terrified of ending up with something tacky/gaudy, so I was hoping to keep it as simple as I can. Not too much blah, you know?

Comment: @Amphiteóth I'm sorry I did not understand the bit about ete and eet. :B